# Testing resque-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

In `resque-scheduler`, how do I rspec-test that some job is queued EVERY 30 seconds?

Here is my `resque-scheduler.yml` file:

```
hipchat_schedule:
 queue: hipchat
 every: 30s
 class: HipChatPolling
```

There is very useful [resque_spec](https://github.com/leshill/resque_spec) gem, but I am not sure if it can do test for `every`-clause.

Comment: resque_spec only allows you to test whether jobs have been queued or not--there's no way using that gem to test the scheduling process (which loads your yaml file).  I'm looking for a gem (and might make one myself if I can't find one) that tests the scheduling process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think this is tested - and have to be tested - by `resque-scheduler` gem (or to be precise, in the `rufus-scheduler` gem), not on your side. If scheduling is not happened then it is not a bug in your application, but a bug in the gem.

But, if you want to test it anyway, you have two way to do it:

- Make some testable change in the job and check it with tests (e.g. touch a file, log start times somewhere, etc
- Monitor Resque's queue and wait until job class appear twice, and calculate an elapsed time between two apperance.

Note, to do this, you have to be sure `Resque.inline` setting is disabled before the test!